# Filter nested arrays using Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I have an array of variations for multiple products. The array shown below has been stripped of unnecessary information but it shows the data I need. These arrays per product may contain 1 to many variations within. I need to get the id for the variation. Let's say the user chooses the color Black and size XL. These options are contained in the attributes array in the first variation therefore the id should be 1023. Is there a way to get the id based on the attributes chosen? I have tried .filter and .first using a for-loop through each variation. I can't make a distinction between option 1 and option 2. I get them returned as options. I've tried .contains() also but that just gives me all of the attributes.

```
[
  {
    "id" : 1023,
    "price" : "89.50",
    "stock_quantity" : 7,
    "virtual" : false,
    "attributes" : [
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "option" : "XL",
        "name" : "Size"
      },
      {
        "id" : 1,
        "option" : "Black",
        "name" : "Color"
      }
    ],
    "sale_price" : "",
    "shipping_class_id" : 0
  },
  {
    "id" : 1022,
    "price" : "89.50",
    "stock_quantity" : 7,
    "virtual" : false,
    "date_on_sale_to" : null,
    "attributes" : [
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "option" : "XL",
        "name" : "Size"
      },
      {
        "id" : 1,
        "option" : "Virtual Pink\/Black",
        "name" : "Color"
      }
    ],
    "sale_price" : "",
    "shipping_class_id" : 0
  }
]
```

Comment: That's JSON, you didn't parse it into custom structs beforehand?

Comment: I did but there are a lot more issues with it. Parsing it the way I did it just adds the attributes as attributes without making a distinction based on the "name".

Comment: If you know all the `name` values, it could be a `enum AttributesNames: String {}` But https://pastebin.com/neAjA1SL might give you some starter.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. The problem I'm having is that sometimes I have products with many variations as shown in that example, I could have many size XL. Maybe I can group the attributes when I parse instead of treating them as separate arrays. I think your comment is leading me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: where is the array?

Comment: Using Codable when decoding would be a good start.